# Python скрыть терминал

Tags: python

Здравствуйте!

Вот такая проблема: есть программа на python 2.6 (на другие версии перейти возможности нет). К программе прикручен графический интерфейс на tkinter. Когда запускаем все это дело, поверх программы появляется окно, все хорошо, все рады. Проблема в том, что под окном tkinter'а висит окно терминала/командной строки, смущающее пользователя. Более того, пользователь любит его закрывать, что вгоняет остальные окна в неадекват. Собственно вопрос такой: как скрыть это окно терминала/командной строки и после (во время) завершения программы показать обратно. Желательно, чтобы скрытие происходило только если *debug == false*. Работать должно в первую очередь под mac os, желатьельно кросплатформенное решение.

Comment: Т.е., программа запускается из терминала, который после запуска должен закрыться?

Comment: self.root.withdraw() - скрыть окно
root.deiconify() - вернуть

Comment: Bumblebee322@, вопрос был задан в те времена, когда я еще не умел упаковывать программы на питоне в exe-шники, и он именно про то, как скрыть терминал (в смысле cmd.exe и пр.). Думаю, этот вопрос нужно удалить или дать на него нормальный ответ вида «ты делаешь что-то не то».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации по питону написано, что нужно поменять расширение с **py** на **pyw**.

Большего к сожалению не скажу. Не знаю питона.

Для использования debug режима можете написать какой-нибудь скриптик, который будет запускать ваше приложение в зависимости от переданных в него параметров (то есть будет на лету переименовывать файл из py в pyw и наоборот).

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но решение сугубо под винду... Если из линукса в терминале запускать, то ничео не скроется... Ладно, пойду еще гуглить.

Comment: @Zelta, так а зачем в линуксе из консоли запускать? Сделайте файл исполняемым и запускайте двойным кликом.

Comment: Ну похоже, что прийдется так. Другого способа не нашел. Всем спасибо!
ЗЫ: а дебаг будет при запуске из консоли)